# Is WolframAlpha computing this radical correctly?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, numerical-methods, computational-mathematics, wolfram-alpha

Is WolframAlpha computing this radical correctly?

[$$\sqrt{\frac{1}{1 + {10}^{-375}}}$$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%281+%2B+%2810%29%5E%28-375%29%29%5E%28-1%29%29%5E%281%2F2%29)

When I double-check again, the inequality:

[$$\sqrt{\frac{1}{1 + {10}^{-x}}} > 1$$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%281+%2B+%2810%29%5E%28-x%29%29%5E%28-1%29%29%5E%281%2F2%29+%3E+1)

leads to a contradiction:

$$\sqrt{{10}^x} > \sqrt{{10}^x + 1}.$$

Is there something wrong with WolframAlpha's numerical approximation of the first radical above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keep hitting the "More digits" button.  Eventually, the approximation gets accurate enough that it shows itself to be below 1.

What you're running in to here is the fact that $10^{-375}$ is very **very** close to 0, so that the fraction is **very** close to 1.

Comment: ... or just try asking WolframAlpha for ((1 + (10)^(-375))^(-1))^(1/2) - 1